# Visual Studio is truncating my HTML text during the build process

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, truncation

This source:

```
<iq-button-async loading="uiStates.updatingPatient"
state-active="[[[Updating]]]"
state-inactive="[[[Update]]]"
disabled="myForm.$invalid || (uiStates.loadingHTs ||     uiStates.loadingAssignedContent || uiStates.loadingAssignedAssessments || uiStates.loadingAssignedActionPlans || uiStates.loadingCalendar)"
ng-click="update()">
</iq-button-async>
```

gets truncated to this:

```
<iq-button-async disabled="myForm.$invalid || (uiStates.loadingHTs ||    uiStates.loadingAssignedContent || uiStates.loadingAssignedAssessments || uiStates.lo" class="ng-isolate-scope" ng-click="update()" state-inactive="Update" state-active="Updating" loading="uiStates.updatingPatient"><button class="btn ng-binding" ng-show="!$ctrl.loading" ng-class="$ctrl.overrideClass ? $ctrl.overrideClass : 'btn-success'" ng-disabled="$ctrl.disabled">
{{ $ctrl.stateInactive }}
<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</button>
<!-- ngIf: $ctrl.disabled -->
<button disabled="disabled" class="btn ng-binding" ng-show="$ctrl.loading" ng-class="$ctrl.overrideClass ? $ctrl.overrideClass : 'btn-success'">
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> {{ $ctrl.stateActive }}...
</button>
</iq-button-async>
```

Why is the code being truncated and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: The disabled= text is truncated at the end.

Comment: Turns out Microsoft Edge limits the "disabled" text to 127 characters.